# Updating Model in Gae datastore server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, maven-gae-plugin

I have a profile class:

```
class profile(db.Model):
  user = db.stringProperty()
  # Other properties ...
  access = db.ListProperty(db.keys)

class apps(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
```

The profile class was there for quiet some time, but we added recently access field which will store the keys of apps.
Now we are adding profile permissions on the app, access field does not get updated in the model.

This works fine totally on localhost, but when I update this on server I get this error
"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access'"
Has anybody come across same situation

**Update:**
Figured out that one of the object from profile class is being returned as None. Here is the code which gets profile object on localhost but None on the server

```
 liuser = users.User(request.POST['user']) 
 #request.POST['user'] gets user Gmail ID, which is being converted to user object
 profiles=Profile.all().filter(" user =", liuser).get()
 userprofile=profiles

 #tried below code which returns "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access'" on server, the same gets a profile object on localhost
 if not hasattr(userprofile, "access"): 
    userprofile.access=[]
```

@Robert hope the formatting is fine now.

Thank You
Sai Krishna

Comment: It is easier to read and answer your question if your code is formatted.

Comment: Could you include the code you are using to read and update profile entities.  You might also want to include the actual code you are using.  Your code has several issues, such as "db.keys" and "db.stringProperty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to fix this. The problem was with users.User object which does not append @gmail.com for gmail users, but while it accepts for other domains with domain name, which was throwing None Type object

Thank You once again for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you add a property to a model, the existing instances of the model that are in the datastore do not automatically get that property.

You will need to modify your handler code that interacts with profile entities to check for the existence of access. Python's `hasattr` function will do. Something like this:

```
a_profile = profile.all().somequerystuffheretogetaninstance().get()
if a_profile is not None:
    if not hasattr(a_profile, "access"):
        a_profile.access = whateveryourdefaultdatais
    # perform my data logic normally after this, but remember to persist
    # this to the datastore to save the new access property.
```

Comment: This would solve my problem, I guess, but what I did, I created whole new application with the new model schema  and changed the name in app.yaml file, even then it did not create the new field. However, I saw a small bug in the code. At first time usage of profile.Access was used instead of profile.access. Would it be the reason for 'access' field not being at other place.